# php - access the returned values from html file

Tags: javascript, php, html, return

I will try to be as brief as possible.

I have a php file with one function. I want that function to return a array which will contain multiple variables.
Next I want to load this array in my html file.

The structure of my php:

```
 <?php
 function solve(){
 if($oblast == "1"){

// 

    switch ($sadzba) {
        case "1": $price1=.... ; break;
        case "2": $price2=.....;break;
 ...

                     }
 }

 $result = array($price1, $price2);
 return $result;
 }solve();
```

And now I want to access to $result in my html file so I can do this for example:

```
 <div id="first"><?php echo $result[0] ?></div>
 <div id="second"><?php echo $result[1] ?></div>
```

How can be this done please?

Comment: When you say "load this array in my *html file*", are you referring to the same html/php file where you generated the array?

Comment: No, php and html are 2 separate files

Comment: I believe your html should be saved as a php file?

Answer (score 1):

in your file do the following:

**Please understand something VERY IMPORTANT: variables in php are not global by default . . so your code will never run until you pass $oblast as paramater to the funciton solve or add global $oblast to it (But the 2nd is highly not recommended)**

```
 <?php
 function solve($oblast){
     if($oblast == "1"){
         switch ($sadzba) {
             case "1": $price1=.... ; break;
             case "2": $price2=.....;break;
         }     
     }   
     $result = array($price1, $price2);
     return $result;
}
$result = solve($oblast); // <-- make sure this variable is set e.g. $oblast = $_POST['something'];
include "path/to/html_file.html";
```

Comment: and what about my html file? Do I have to include something, or load something with jquery?

Comment: Check the rest of the answer above, please market it correct if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. I push the submit button, I pass form values to that php file, but the result is not showing. Do you have any other idea?